# Add image to graph footer in Altair

Tags: python, altair

Is there a way to add a logo or image, for example, on the footer of an Altair plot? Like this example image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1fsq.png) on the following graph:

```
import altair as alt

from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()

one = alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
).properties(
    title = "Miles per gallon and Horsepower",
    width = 300,
    height = 300
)

alt.concat(one).properties(
    title=alt.TitleParams(
        ['Source: blablabla.', '@jballesterosc_'],
        baseline='bottom',
        orient='bottom',
        anchor='end',
        fontWeight='normal',
        fontSize=10
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a [Layer Chart](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#layer-chart) with an [Image Mark](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks.html#user-guide-image-mark). For example:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()

one = alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
).properties(
    title = "Miles per gallon and Horsepower",
    width = 300,
    height = 300
)

img = alt.Chart({
    "values": [{"url": "https://i.imgur.com/zHqeoHB.png"}]
}).mark_image(opacity=0.5).encode(
    x=alt.value(270), x2=alt.value(300),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(320), y2=alt.value(350),  # pixels from top
    url="url:N"
)

alt.layer(one, img)
```

[image]

notice that the `x`, `x2`, `y`, and `y2` encodings here are specified as pixel values, and control the horizontal and vertical extent of the image. By setting them to values larger than the specified chart bounds, the image will appear outside the chart axis.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Jake. I've tried to create the layer chart using my example from above, but I got the following error: `Concatenated charts cannot be layered.`

Comment: You’re only concating a single chart, so you can safely remove the concatenation and put the title on the layer chart.